# Rendering SVG file in flutter is not working

Tags: android, flutter, adobe-xd

I am trying to render the SVG file in my flutter application using the "flutter_svg 0.17.1" package.
It's working fine with most of the online SVG files but it's not working with my custom SVG design which I download from the wireframe.

[Wire frame design](https://xd.adobe.com/view/8cd76b91-61ee-4bc8-473b-45fa935fcc98-fae6/)

[dog.svg](https://www.svgrepo.com/show/2046/dog.svg)

```
   String assetName = "images/dog.svg"; // This one is working
   String assetName1 = "images/splash.svg"; // Not working

   final Widget svgIcon = SvgPicture.asset(
        assetName,
        semanticsLabel: 'A red up arrow'
    );
```

Any guideline that I have to follow while downloading SVG files from adobe xd

Comment: specify 'not working'

Answer (score 0):

Remove shadows and filter effects